# Chrome Extension Img replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm having chrome extension injection problems, where I am trying to replace an image src, but it doesn't seem to work, I'm not sure if this is because the images are supplied from API. I have tested my script on other pages and images on the same page but these images just wont change.

Code of image I'm trying to adjust:

```
<div class="skin-item topskins covert skinus4961422" data-cost="45" data-uid="4961422">
    <div class="uavat"><img alt="Benjamin" src="https://steamcdn-a.opskins.media/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f149864f9810294b162ad1f7845db70b175aaff5_full.jpg"></div>
    <div class="itemcost">
        $45
    </div>
    <div class="skinimg"><img alt="Sephora eGift Card $45" class="skin" src="https://static.wax.io/d-img/dynamic-apps/img/sephora-mpStQQL.png"></div>
    <div class="itemname" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #9cf448">
        Sephora eGift Card $45
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the jquery code I have written in an attempt to replace the icon.

```
$("img").each(function(i, elem){

  if ($(this).attr("src") == "https://static.wax.io/d-img/dynamic-apps/img/sephora-mpStQQL.png"){

  $(this).attr("src", "https://static.wax.io/d-img/dynamic-apps/img/accessories-bonnie-clyde-bonnie-clide-pico-51mm-round-browbar-sunglasses-gravity-black-bced6228b8.png");

  }

  });
```

If anyone can help solve, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just checked your code and it works https://jsfiddle.net/mwk5xbud/

Comment: Are you running this script after DOM content was loaded or earlier?

Comment: If the page content is generated dynamically by the page script, which is common in modern web, you need to use MutationObserver to detect it.

Comment: Here is an example of problem - https://youtu.be/gpXjmDAavu8 - I have tried editing other assets on site, including logo and it worked fine. Just items will not work.

Comment: @wOxxOm if I were to be using MutationObserver, how would I implement it into this code?

Comment: Maybe someone will adapt it for you but I think there should be no problem finding an example and adapting it.